# Homebrew aspell directory not writable

Tags: homebrew, aspell

I am having some difficulties. This started with a broader question but I seem (with some help from this list) to have narrowed things down a bit. My original query is at [Emacs - Kieran Healy's Emacs Starter Kit aspell English dictionery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272141/emacs-kieran-healys-emacs-starter-kit-aspell-english-dictionery)

(And, yes, I am embarrassed at the spelling error in the title).

I have narrowed (with some help from that question) to narrow my problem down to the Homebrew installation of aspell. The command `brew install aspell` gives the following error.

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink lib/aspell-0.60/american-variant_0.alias
/usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60 is not writable.

You can try again using:
brew link aspell
```

If I try `brew link aspell` I get the following error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/aspell/0.60.6.1_1... 
Error: Could not symlink lib/aspell-0.60/american-variant_0.alias
/usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60 is not writable.
```

File permissions on aspell are

```
drwxr-xr-x  89 root  wheel  2848  7 Nov  2016 aspell-0.60
```

`brew doctor` gives

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that 
depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on 
these:
aspell
```

It also tells me I need to update from XCode 9.3 to XCode 10.1, but since I am still running MacOS 10.13.4, I think I do not need to do this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The info at [Homebrew: Could not symlink, /usr/local/bin is not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable?rq=1) was helpful. I had to `sudo chown -R`whoami`:admin /usr/local/lib`. Then after unintalling and reinstalling aspell with Homebrew, I had to `brew link --overwrite aspell`. Everything works now.